# Armazenar arquivo com mais de 1 Mb MySQL

Tags: mysql, delphi-7

Estou tentando gravar um arquivo em uma base de dados mySQL usando delphi.

Para arquivos com tamanho menor que 1Mb esta funcionando perfeitamente, porém para arquivo com tamanho maior estou tendo problemas.

Acontece o seguinte erro: "MySQL server has gone away".

A ideia inicial seria salvar um arquivo do tipo exe.

O tipo para este campo na tabela está como MediumBlob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prezado

Isto pode ser um erro de timeout e não de armazenamento. 
Medium Blob, em tese, armazena até 16MB (Versão 5.7) de acordo com a [documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/storage-requirements.html).

Verifique o arquivo de configuração do MySQL, exemplo: /etc/mysql/my.cnf,
mude ou acrescente os parâmetros (caso não existam). Se você utilizar Wamp altere o my.ini.

**wait_timeout = 3600**

**max_allowed_packet = 128M**

reinicie o mysql, por exemplo:

sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart

Veja se deu certo.